# How to split a comma (or any delimiter) seperated string using sys.dm_fts_parser?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Well, for a given input like

```
Name    MobileNumber
Name1   1111111111,22222222222,3333333333,4444444444
Name2   5555555555,6666666666
```

And to get an output of the form

```
Name    splitdata
Name1   1111111111
Name1   22222222222
Name1   3333333333
Name1   4444444444
Name2   5555555555
Name2   6666666666
```

There are [many ways](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/codes/code1797-split-function-in-sql-server-using-set-base-approach.aspx)  to accomplish e.g.

```
Declare @t Table (Name Varchar(10),MobileNumber Varchar(50))
Insert Into @t Values
('Name1','1111111111,22222222222,3333333333,4444444444'),
('Name2','5555555555,6666666666')

select F1.Name, 
 O.splitdata 
 from
 (
 select *,
 cast('<X>'+replace(F.MobileNumber,',','</X><X>')+'</X>' as XML) as xmlfilter
 from @t F
 )F1
 cross apply
 ( 
 select fdata.D.value('.','varchar(50)') as splitdata 
 from f1.xmlfilter.nodes('X') as fdata(D)) O
```

However, I just came across [sys.dm_fts_parser](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280463.aspx) and thought of achieving the same using that but failed. My attempt

```
SELECT Name,display_term
 FROM @t
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_fts_parser('"' + MobileNumber + '"', 1033, 0,0)
```

Could anyone please help me in doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

```
where display_term NOT LIKE 'nn%'
```

Full query

```
SELECT Name,display_term
FROM @t
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_fts_parser('"' + MobileNumber + '"', 1033, 0,0)
where display_term NOT LIKE 'nn%'
```